# Which should be singleton in one application? MongoClient or MongoDatabase or MongoCollection?

Tags: java, mongodb

As mentioned in the docs:
http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.3/driver/getting-started/quick-tour/

> The MongoClient instance actually represents a pool of connections to the database; you will only need one instance of class MongoClient even with multiple threads.

Using codes below can get the collection(just like 'table' in the RDMS):

```
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("mydb");
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("test");
```

I found  these code always return new instances, so,how about making the **MongoDatabase** or **MongoCollection** as the Singleton in my applicaiton?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MongoClient should typically be the singleton. Your quote mentions this

> The MongoClient instance actually represents a pool of connections to
>   the database; you will only need one instance of class MongoClient
>   even with multiple threads.

It also mentions this in the [javadocs](http://api.mongodb.com/java/3.0/com/mongodb/MongoClient.html):

> A MongoDB client with internal connection pooling. For most
>   applications, you should have one MongoClient instance for the entire
>   JVM.

It does not make sense to have *MongoDatabase* or *MongoCollection* as singletons mainly (there are other reasons) because the underlying connection can get stale, which requires some coding to refresh a singleton MongoDatabase or singleton MongoCollection.